# Auto Arima and Arima do not have the same result in python

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I used the following codes for Auto Arima:

```
import pmdarima as pmd
from pmdarima import auto_arima
stepwise_fit=auto_arima(dataset['POPRATE],seasonal=False,trace=True,supress_warnings=False)
[autoarima][1]
[autoarimaresult][1]
```

codes for arima

```
import statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
model=ARIMA(dataset['POPRATE],order(2,0,1))
[arima result][1]
```

I am a newbie in python. feedback would be appreciated

Comment: Hello, your question is quite succinct, and nothing says why the auto-arima and the arima model should have the same result. Unless you expect the `auto_arima` method to exactly call the `ARIMA` model with your exact same parameters, there's no real reason to assume that both should return the same result.